# What are the numbers in glib errors and warnings?

Tags: glib

```
(myapp:11228): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_date_strftime: assertion `slen > 0' failed
```

What does the number after myapp mean? It doesn't correspond to any source-code line nor does its hex or binary interpretation correspond to a relevant location in the binary. The number has always mystified me and looking at the GLib source it appears that it is supposed to be a line number. What does the number mean, or what is it supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's the [pid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier), in case you want to track down the process that emitted the message and say, attach a debugger.